# pmap_dbl is not working with lambda function

Tags: r

I am trying to find the sum of columns rowwise using `pmap_dbl`. If I use `sum` instead of `\(x) sum(x)` it is working. Any ideas?

```r
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)
country_df <- tibble(
  population = c(328, 38, 30, 56, 1393, 126, 57),
  population2 = c(133, 12, 99, 83, 1033, 101, 33),
  population3 = c(89, 39, 33, 56, 193, 126, 58),
  pop = 45
)
# working
country_df |> mutate(sum = pmap_dbl(pick(1:3),sum))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#>   population population2 population3   pop   sum
#>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1        328         133          89    45   550
#> 2         38          12          39    45    89
#> 3         30          99          33    45   162
#> 4         56          83          56    45   195
#> 5       1393        1033         193    45  2619
#> 6        126         101         126    45   353
#> 7         57          33          58    45   148

# not working
country_df |> mutate(sum = pmap_dbl(pick(1:3), \(x) sum(x)))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `sum = pmap_dbl(pick(1:3), function(x) sum(x))`.
#> Caused by error in `pmap_dbl()`:
#> ℹ In index: 1.
#> Caused by error in `.f()`:
#> ! unused arguments (population = .l[[1]][[i]], population2 = .l[[2]][[i]], population3 = .l[[3]][[i]])
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─dplyr::mutate(country_df, sum = pmap_dbl(pick(1:3), function(x) sum(x)))
#>   2. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
#>   3. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
#>   4. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   5. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
#>   6. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
#>   7. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
#>   8. ├─purrr::pmap_dbl(...)
#>   9. │ └─purrr:::pmap_("double", .l, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
#>  10. │   ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
#>  11. │   │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  12. │   └─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
#>  13. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
#>  14.   └─purrr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  15.     └─cli::cli_abort(...)
#>  16.       └─rlang::abort(...)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `\(x){}` is a lambda with exactly one input argument.  you can use `...` as per the answer below, or `\(x,y,z){}` if you predictably have exaclty three arguments.

Answer (score 3):

`pmap` is a bit different than `map` or `map2` functions where the number of values that you can pass is fixed. In `pmap` functions you can pass any number of arguments which can be captured with three dots. (`...`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

country_df |> mutate(sum = pmap_dbl(pick(1:3), \(...) sum(...)))

#  population population2 population3   pop   sum
#       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1        328         133          89    45   550
#2         38          12          39    45    89
#3         30          99          33    45   162
#4         56          83          56    45   195
#5       1393        1033         193    45  2619
#6        126         101         126    45   353
#7         57          33          58    45   148
```

Comment: But with ```apply``` it is working. ```country_df |> mutate(sum = apply(pick(1:3), 1, \(x)sum(x)))```. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: lapply takes the whole frame( `pick(1:3)` ) and uses margin=1 that you gave it to know how to split it up and feed to the \(x); notice that you cant use apply without that, or with margin=2 and not get an error.